# Transfer student Apple Care to another user

Tags: applecare

I was wondering, if I purchased Apple Care as a student can I transfer it to someone else when I sell the device(s)? I've found a similar question on here but it didn't address specifically Apple Care purchased as a student.

Also if it is possible, how do you do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can transfer AppleCare to another person subject the terms and conditions in the location you live.  Whether this is a student-purchase or not doesn't make a difference.

You didn't mention the country you live so I'll assume you're in the US for this info.  (you'll need to look-up the T&C's for your own country if not in the US).

Here's a snippet from [Apple's AppleCare T&C](https://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/applecare/applecareplus/docs/applecareplusmacus.html) for a Mac.  It tells you how to transfer the AppleCare to someone else.:

> ### 10. Transfer of Plan.
>
> Subject to the restrictions set forth below, you may make a one-time
>   permanent transfer of all of your rights under the Plan to another
>   party, provided that: **(a)** you transfer to the other party the original
>   proof of purchase, the Plan's Confirmation, the Plan’s printed
>   materials and this service contract; **(b)** you notify Apple of the
>   transfer by sending, faxing or e-mailing notice of transfer to Apple
>   Inc., ATTN: Agreement Administration, MS: 217-AC, 2511 Laguna Blvd,
>   Elk Grove, CA 95758, U.S., fax number 916-405-4175 or
>   agmts_transfer@apple.com, respectively, and **(c)** the other party
>   accepts the terms of this service contract. When notifying Apple of
>   the transfer, you must provide the Plan Agreement Number, the serial
>   number of the Covered Equipment, and the name, address, telephone
>   number and email address of the new owner.

Make sure you follow a, b, and c to correctly perform the transfer.  Keep a record of what you send to Apple and how they respond back to you.

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect Apple would have let you do this. Nice find! Very helpful to know.